# resultSetToTableModel cannot find symbol

Tags: java, mysql, compiler-errors

```
private void DisplayTr() {
    try {
        Con = DriverManager
             .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:????/atmdatabase","root","");
        St = Con.createStatement();
        Rs = St.executeQuery("select * from TransactionTbl where AccNum = "+MyAccNum+"");
        MiniTbl.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(Rs)); //ERROR
    } catch(Exception e) {
            
    }
}
```

I imported

```java
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;`
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
```

and `dbutils` in dependencies.

I'm trying to show the Transaction of my ATM system in Table (Mini Statement).

Comment: [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

Comment: Do you get the error when you compile your code? Are you referring to this [DbUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/examples.html)? Are you using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/)? What Java version? What [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)?

Comment: Not necessarily related to your problem, nonetheless if that empty `catch` block is your actual code, then that is usually not a good idea. I suggest you add `e.printStackTrace();` to that `catch` block. Also, if you are using at least Java 7, then you should consider using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: You should also consider adopting [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: Are you using [rs2xml.jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/finalangelsanddemons/files/) ?

Comment: Im using Maven and im using netbeans IDE

Comment: the only error is the "resultSetToTableModel"  cannot find symbol